# SAS--- Merge Data Based On subject ID and Date (Within and Across Files)

Tags: loops, date, join, merge, sas

Here are two sample SAS data sets (they are all fake datasets)

- outpatient
  https://drive.google.com/open?id=179_L_qnZdKY5-EZnwy4BEzyEZP-VT-in
- inpatient https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vhUa_yTflLEXSR6xdZG_hOYxCPRnXVkw

I did not distinguish between filtered/master here, but it's easy to create filters (any random filter that restrict the dataset to a smaller one will serve as an example, it will work even if you don't distinguish, just duplicate and rename one as master and another as filtered)

I have two datasets that look like this, study inter-hospital transfer
My dataset is enormous. I am able to do the whole thing in SAS, but is very very very slow :((( I will show my code here, but I am seeking ways to improve running time.

```
  master_inpatient
   ID   admsn_dt    thru_dt      prvdr_num       
    341   2013-04-01  2013-04-02    G
    230   2013-06-01  2013-06-03    I
    232   2013-07-31  2013-07-31    F
    124   2013-04-29  2013-04-29    C
    232   2013-07-31  2013-08-20    Q

  filtered_inpatient
   ID   admsn_dt    thru_dt      prvdr_num       
    341   2013-04-01  2013-04-02    G
    232   2013-07-31  2013-07-31    F
    232   2013-07-31  2013-08-20    Q

   master_outpatient
   ID     thru_dt     prvdr_num
    348   2013-09-23   Z
    124   2013-04-29   A
    331   2013-06-14   G
    439   2013-02-01   B
    331   2013-06-14   D

   filtered_outpatient
   ID     thru_dt     prvdr_num
    124   2013-04-29   A
    331   2013-06-14   G
    439   2013-02-01   B
    331   2013-06-14   D
```

I have two master datasets: an inpatient dataset and an outpatient dataset, 
and two filtered datasets: some filter on diganosis (e.g., including only patients with diagnosis of TB) is applied to the master dataset, make the dataset shorter than master dataset.

`ID` is patient ID, and `admsn_dt` is the day you are admitted to a hospital, `thru_dt` is the day you are discharged/transferred. Outpatient only has a `thru_dt` because in outpatient setting you don't need to be admitted into the hospital to be treated.

Consider four types of transfers that can occur amongst the `INPATIENT` and `OUTPATIENT` data sets.

- outpatient setting (ER) to an inpatient setting,
- an inpatient setting to an outpatient setting (ER),
- an outpatient setting (ER) to an outpatient setting (ER), and,
- an inpatient setting to an inpatient setting (ER).

I want the filtered dataset (filtered_inpatient or filtered_outpatient) to be the origin and master datasets (master_inpatient and master_outpatient) to be the destination because a patient need to be satisfied with some diagnosis, and then what we care is where he/she transferred (the patient doesn't need to have that diagnosis at the destination)

In Sum: The four transfer type are:

- if outpatient → inpatient: filtered_outpatient(ID, thru_dt) → master_inpatient(ID, admsn_dt)
- if outpatient → outpatient: filtered_outpatient(ID, thru_dt) → master_outpatient(ID,thru_dt)
- if inpatient → inpatient: filtered_inpatient(ID, thru_dt) → master_inpatient(ID,admsn_dt)
- if inpatient → outpatient: filtered_inpatient(ID, thru_dt) → master_inpatient(ID,thru_dt)

What I'd like to do is to create a dataset of *same/first day* transfers based on these conditions:

- For each person, if the `prvdr_num` (provider number) are different, and the difference in date is less than 1 day (0 or 1).
- Compute `transtype` that indicates type of transfer. For example: from inpatient to outpatient is `inpout`.  The others would be `inpinp`, `outout` and `outinp`

The final dataset should look something like this:

```
   df3
   ID   fromdate     todate     from_prvdr  to_prvdr    d     transtype
    124   2013-04-29   2013-04-29  C           A          0      inpout
    232   2013-07-31   2013-07-31  F           Q          0      inpinp
    331   2013-06-14   2013-06-14  G           D          0      outout
```

Another thing is that, when matching within file, it's highly likely that you get something like this:

```
ID   fromdate     todate       from_prvdr    to_prvdr
1    3/30/2011    3/31/2011    43291         48329
1    3/31/2011    3/30/2011    48329         43291

OR 

ID   fromdate     todate       from_prvdr    to_prvdr
1    3/31/2011    3/31/2011    43291         48329
1    3/31/2011    3/31/2011    48329         43291

(In this latter case I can just exclude duplicate by date later in R, but I need to get rid of the first case)
```

Here is what I tried (and succeeded).

```
#this is an example of outpatient--> inpatient
#all variables in master datasets have an i prefix

proc sort data= etl.master_inpatient;
    by iID iadmsn_dt; 
run;

proc sort data= etl.filtered_outpatient;
    by ID thru_dt; 
run;

data fnl.matchdate_inpinp;
   set etl.master_inpatient end = eof;
      do p = 1 to num;
         set etl.filtered_outpatient nobs = num point = p;
         if iID = ID then do;
            d = abs(iadmsn_dt-thru_dt);
            put iID = ID = iadmsn_dt = thru_dt= d =;

         if d <= 1 then output;
         end;
         else continue;
      end;
      put '===========================';
   if eof then stop;
run;
```

There is no error in the code, but I have to do this seperately for four types of transfer, and merge them together in R later. I took me more than two days to finish running one year's data, I really want something more efficient as I have 8 year data.

Q: What are some examples of techniques that speed up the process of creating the transfers data set ?

Also, as I said, when matching within file, it is likely that we get some repetitive results (like described above), i really hope this can be solved.

Comment: How many rows and columns are in the enormous data set ?  Are there indices on the data sets ?

Answer (score 0):

So for each record in the master inpatient file, you are iterating through the entire filtered outpatient dataset which is essentially a cartesian product and hence take a lot of time. I can see multiple places where you can gain some efficiencies:

1. You could change `set etl.filtered_outpatient nobs = num point = p;` to `set etl.filtered_outpatient (where = (Id = iID and (iadmsn_dt-thru - 1 <= thru_dt <= iadmsn_dt-thru + 1))) nobs = num ;` and remove the `if` conditions below. You are essentially now looping though only records where the IDs are equal and the dates fall within the 1 day range which will gain some efficiencies. If it is possible to build an index on ID and thru_dt for filtered_outpatient, it will become significantly fast.
2. You can use `PROC SQL` cartesian product which can be little more faster (this is based on my empirical experience)

```
create table matchdate_inpinpas    
    select a.*, b.* /* Or what columns you need to keep */
    from master_inpatient a, filtered_outpatient b
    where b.Id = aiID and (a.iadmsn_dt-thru - 1 <= b.thru_dt <= a.iadmsn_dt-thru + 1);
quit;
```

Again, indexing will make this very fast.

3. You could break this by parts and submit in parallel. A simple way to do it would be to say break it down to 10 parts based on the first digit of ID (assuming they have a uniform distribution - else different part will take different times to run).

So you may write a macro that looks like:

```
%macro process (part);

create table matchdate_inpinpas_part&p
    select a.*, b.* /* Or what columns you need to keep */
    from master_inpatient a, filtered_outpatient b
    where b.Id = aiID and 
          (a.iadmsn_dt-thru - 1 <= b.thru_dt <= a.iadmsn_dt-thru + 1)
          and substr(ID, 1, 1) = "&pt";
          /* If ID is numeric you may need a type conversion */
quit; 

%mend.

%part(0); /* Call multiple times with different values */
```

You will extend this to more than 10 parts and speed up things quite a bit.